# Can I avoid using `asmatrix`?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any way for me to create matrices directly and not have to use [`asmatrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asmatrix.html)? From what I can see, all of the typical matrix functions (`ones`, `rand`, etc) in Numpy return arrays, not matrices, which means (according to the documentation) that `asmatrix` will copy the data. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> Unlike matrix, asmatrix does not make a copy if the input is already a
>   matrix or an ndarray. Equivalent to matrix(data, copy=False).

So, `asmatrix` does *not* copy the data if it doesn't need to:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
>>> b = np.asmatrix(a)
>>> b.base is a
True
>>> a[0] = 3
>>> b
matrix([[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]])
```